# How to make a SvelteKit SPA prerender index.html

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit application that I'm building with static adapter.

I'm setting a `fallback` in svelte.config to make it a SPA.

```json
{
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: 'index.html'
        })
    }
}
```

In `/routes` I have a folder called `(prerendered)` that has a `+layout.js` file with `export const prerender = true;` as described in the [svelte docs here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender).

If I put my root `+page.svelte` and a tree of nested article and marketing pages into that (prerendered) folder, I get prerendered html files for the articles, but not for index.html.

Is there a way to prerender index.html in a static SPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what the `fallback` is for. It serves to resolve dynamic routes that have not been or cannot be pre-rendered and thus not served by a simple file server, all it does is route to a page.

If you already have a `+page.svelte` you want to use as the index, you should *not* set `fallback`. The page for the root route will automatically be turned into an `index.html`.

Comment: Trouble is, it is an SPA. I'm only looking to prerender a small portion of the app for better SEO. If I remove the fallback I get an error "@sveltejs/adapter-static: cannot have dynamic routes unless using the 'fallback' option. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode for more information"

Comment: You should write the fallback to a different file then. It depends on how/where you want to deploy the site and whether that environment actually supports fallbacks. E.g. if you want to deploy to GitHub pages, you would want to write a `404.html` fallback, because that is served if a file is not found, which will happen for dynamic routes.

Comment: I’m having the same issue.

https://github.com/wiverson/static-spa-testi

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/7885

This was working a month ago, starting to think this might be regression.

Comment: @WillIverson The thing I didn't understand is that your `fallback` doesn't actually need to exist in your routes. It just has to match whatever your host has configured. I'm using firebase hosting, so can manually configure that to a non-existent `/app.html`.